# Yii2: How to allow Guzzle POST requests in a controller

Tags: yii, yii2, guzzle, yii2-advanced-app, bad-request

I’m trying to make a POST request via Guzzle to a Yii controller but getting a "Bad Request #400". I thought when I don’t use behaviours() the controller is automatically accessible to all kinds of requests, but nope. How I can solve this? What would be best practice for CURL/Guzzle requests in Yii2?

```
class ImportController extends yii\web\Controller {
   public function actionIndex() {
      return 'OK';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a rest controller instance (`yii\rest\ActiveController`) and implement authentication for it as described here: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-authentication

That is probably the correct approach to your use case, and you would not have to deal with CSRF.